# How to show numerical values into tensorboard

Tags: tensorboard

I have implemented a very simple computational graph, and I am able to visualize it correctly on tensorboard.

However, when I run the graph, I am not able to see the numerical value of the variables

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(5, name = 'a')
b = tf.constant(5, name = 'b')
c = a + b
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(c))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('c:/users/gpapari/documents/python', sess.graph)
    writer.close()
```

Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are creating two seperate sessions. 
Second, you need to add the values you want to track to the filewriter.
To do that you have to create scalars.
In the example I merged all the scalars so you won't have to add the scalars one by one if you want to add more

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.constant(5, name = 'a')
b = tf.constant(5, name = 'b')
c = a + b

tf.summary.scalar("c", c)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('log', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    merged_value , _ =sess.run([merged,c])
    writer.add_summary(merged_value, 1)

writer.close()
```

Also you don't have to define the entire path for the filewriter. You can use a relative path.